# Best method for writing http request for ui select2

Tags: angularjs

I'm the new comer for angular js can any one suggest me some idea how to use http request for the uiselect2 tool and also how can i use the options in the uiselect2 such as minimum input length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('YouCtrl',function($scope,$http){

   $http.post('YouURL',{youdatatosend}).success(function(data){
     alert('success');

   }).error(function(){
    alert('error');
   })
 });
```